# Split string with positional values separated by delimiter Java

Tags: java, string

I have an input string that contains 4 ids separated by delimiter(||). I am using the following code:

```
String idString = "id1||id2||id3||id4";

  String ids[] = idString.split("\\|\\|");
  String id1 = ids[0];
  String id2 = ids[1];
  String id3 = ids[2];
  String id4 = ids[3];
```

But there are cases where not all ids are present like :

```
String idString = "||id2||||";
```

In the above scenario the split won't happen in 4 parts and it is not able to tell which id is missing in the split array.

Can someone help with an efficient solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the length and a loop to tell which one is present.  Use `-1` in split to process all delimiters.

```
String idString = "||id2||||";

String ids[] = idString.split("\\|\\|", -1);
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("id[%d] -> %s%n", i, ids[i].isEmpty() ? "is Empty" :ids[i]);
}
```

prints

```
id[0] -> is Empty
id[1] -> id2
id[2] -> is Empty
id[3] -> is Empty
```